# PHP Insert Record into MySQL DB (Multiple recorded are being added)

Tags: php, mysql

I am having problems with this code:

```
<?php
$new_value = 'testing';

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("my_db", $con);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO myDB (myField) VALUES ('$new_value')");

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

2 issues are happening:

1st - 2 records are being inserted instead of 1

2nd - $new_value is not changed and it's creating multiple instances with the same $new_value value when I only want 1.

Comment: Where in your code is $new_value supposed to change? Or do you mean that you insert the same value into the DB over and over again? That is correct because I don't see you specifying anything about unique values or nothing.

Comment: Correct I inserted the same value into the DB over and over again and only want one

Comment: Are you sure you are not executing this code segment twice(e.g. `include/require`)? It seems impossible for two records to be inserted instead of single one....

Comment: Is this the whole code? or maybe just a snippet and this code is somewhere in a loop?

Comment: I'm sure....because I just commented the code above and nothing was inserted into the db

Comment: why you want to try insert if value is in database? or use `replace `instead of `insert`

Comment: Seems like this is not whole code..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is something similar to what you are after, after reading your comment:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO tablename (fields)
VALUES(values);
```

> Use INSERT IGNORE rather than INSERT. If a record doesn't duplicate an existing record, MySQL inserts it as usual. If the record is a duplicate, the IGNORE keyword tells MySQL to discard it silently without generating an error.

**edit**
Or as Vytautas points out; if you want to *replace* the value use REPLACE in stead of INSERT

Comment: INSERT IGNORE is still adding it twice

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you try using transactions? It helps you to avoid some of insert/update errors:

```
 try
    {

        // Start TRANSACTION
        mysqli_autocommit($con, false);

        mysqli_query('INSERT INTO table SET field = "'.$fieldValue.'"');

        // If there is no error then COMMIT
        mysqli_commit($con);      

    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {

        // If there is an error, then rollback any INSERTS or UPDATES in the TRY block
        mysqli_rollback($con);

        $theError = $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Its highly recommended that you use Try/Catch blocks in your code when working with databases.

Answer (score 0):

> 2nd - $new_value is not changed and it's creating multiple instances
>   with the same $new_value value when I only want 1.

Where is $new_value changed ? How is it changed ? Are you sure you are not pressing the browser refresh button many times ?

Comment: There will only be 1 instance of $new_value so, say $new_value = 'Value1'; ... The code is adding itself twice in the db table, I want to avoid duplicates